# "Prefix" before "unicode(entry.title.text, "utf-8")"

Tags: python

I'm editing a script which gets the name of a video url and the line of code that does this is:

```
title = unicode(entry.title.text, "utf-8")
```

It can be found [here](https://github.com/AndrewNeo/groompbot/blob/master/groompbot.py). Is there a simple way to add a predefined prefix before this?
For example if there is a Youtube video named "test", the script should show "Testing Videos: test".

Answer (score 5):

Just prepend a unicode string:

```
title = u'Testing Videos: ' + unicode(entry.title.text, "utf-8")
```

or use string formatting for more complex options; like adding both a prefix and a postfix:

```
title = u'Testing Videos: {} (YouTube)'.format(unicode(entry.title.text, "utf-8"))
```

All that `unicode(inputvalue, codec)` does is decode a byte string to a `unicode` value; you are free to concatenate that with other `unicode` values, including `unicode` literals.

An alternative spelling would be to use the `str.decode()` method on the `entry.title.text` object:

```
title = u'Testing Videos: ' + entry.title.text.decode("utf-8")
```

but the outcome would be the same.